# When an instance is deallocated under ARC, are all its strong pointers automatically set to nil?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, null

I've looked all over for the answer to this, and all the tutorials of ARC I've seen never make this explicitly clear:

I'm using ARC.  If an instance is deallocated (because the last strong pointer to it was set to nil), does that instance's strong pointers also automatically get set to nil and/or whatever objects it points to get deallocated?

For example:  I have two classes, Foo and Bar, and I have an instance of Foo, myFoo.

Inside myFoo, I create an instance of Bar (which is strong by default).

```
Bar *myBar = [Bar new];
```

Now, in whatever instance that owns myFoo, I deallocated it.

```
myFoo = nil;
```

Does the myBar automatically go to nil (or more precisely, its retain count decremented)?

EDIT

I've narrowed it down to this code. I'm using sprite kit. This code is inside an instance which is owned by my Play view.

```
// tick marks every 20 pix.
for (long h=0; h<20000; h+=20) {

    SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode node];
    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 0, h+yOffset+5);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 10, h+yOffset+5);
    line.path = pathToDraw;
    line.lineWidth = 1;
    [line setStrokeColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [rulerContainer addChild:line];
    CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);
}
```

(I know I should be lazy loading the tick marks; this puts 1000 of them there all at once, but it runs fast so figured it was ok; and they should be getting deallocated anyway).

When I comment-out [rulerContainer addChild:line], the allocation problem drops to almost zero.
When that line is in, it's 5MB added every time I go back to Menu view.

Why should the lines be hanging around after the scene and view controller are deallocated?

UPDATE

I added this to my VC based on another thread on SO...

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    if (self.scene != nil)
    {
        [self.scene removeAllActions];
        [self.scene removeAllChildren];

        self.scene = nil;

        [self.skView presentScene:nil];

        self.skView = nil;
    }
}
```

.. but you SHOULDN'T have to do this.  Anyway, this solved the problem.  Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: FYI - an instance is deallocated when its reference count becomes zero, not when the last strong pointer is set to `nil`. And yes, when an instance is deallocated, any strong ivars it has a reference to are released (retain count decremented). No need for anything to be set to `nil`.

Comment: Hi Maddy - thanks for the quick answer. the reason I'm asking is that in Instruments/Allocations, I see my allocations going up by about 5MB every time I move back and forth between my Menu view and Play view (a game). I have no retain cycles. In my prepareForSegue code I set my pointer to Play view to nil.  I don't have any other references to it.  I'm using a nav. controller.  So my Play instance should be totally removed from memory, right?

Comment: Add a `dealloc` method to your view controller and see if it's called when you dismiss the view controller. If not then you do have a reference cycle. Use Instruments Allocations to find out what still has the reference.

Comment: Yes, dealloc is getting called.  But I still have about 5MB higher allocation every time I move back to Menu view. All I'm doing is going to Play view, then Menu, repeat.. if there was a retain cycle down inside the play view (between two objects instantiated by the Play view), should they get released anyway since Play is getting deallocated?

Comment: TL;DR: Nope, they won't be released. As Maddy mentioned, as long as retain count of an object is not 0, it is kept in memory. Thus, it is not entirely correct to speak about "inner" and "outer" variables – you have no object graph analyzed (that's what real GC does; ARC just automates reference counting for it full stop).

Comment: Take a look at my code above.  How could a retain loop be caused by this?

Comment: As many comments already said, yes the myBar would be released by myFoo. But that doesn't necessarily mean that myBar will be deallocated as something else could be referencing myBar. Based on the code you presented, I'm assuming sceneKit is doing some black magic. You could use instruments to find what is retaining the myBar if that truly is the object that is causing the memory leak